# Linker Option at the very end in Eclipse CDT

Tags: c, eclipse, build, linker-flags

I am trying to build a C program in Eclipse CDT that uses `Opus` and `Alsa` libraries. I normally compile the program in command line as follows:

```
cc prog.c -o prog.exe -lopus -lasound
```

but I couldn't achieve the same in eclipse CDT. I add the linker flags at

```
Project > Properties > C/C++ Build > Settings > Tool Settings > GCC C Linker > Miscellaneous
```

resulting command during build by Eclipse is :

```
gcc -lopus -lasound -o "prog" ./src/prog.o
```

How can I make Eclipse put the linker flags at the very end? Otherwise, the code doesn't compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't add libraries as `-lopus` under `Miscellaneous`. Rather, add them under `Project > Properties > C/C++ Build > Settings > Tool Settings > GCC C Linker > Libraries`, in the `Libraries (-l)` listbox. In there, just put the name of the library without the `-l`.

Alternatively, you can list your libraries in `Project > Properties > C/C++ General > Paths and Symbols > Libraries`.